# Passport-local e Passport sempre retorna falso

Tags: node.js, passport-js

Estou usando o Passport e o Passport-local para fazer uma autenticação com o Nodejs, porém, o método req.isAuthenticated sempre me retorna falso, não chega nem a serializar quando eu faço o login. Já tentei colocar um req.logIn() mas ai me dá um outro erro: **serializing user:false Error: Failed to serialize user into session**

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config/database');
var cors = require('cors');

mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err, db){
    if(!err){
        console.log('Conectado');
    }
});

var passport = require('passport');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'SecretSession'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors());

var initPassport = require('./config/passport');
initPassport(passport);


var index = require('./config/index')(passport);
app.use('/', index);

server.listen(3030, function(){
    console.log('Rodando ');
});
```

passport.js:

```
var User = require('../app/models/user');
var login = require('./login');
var signup = require('./signup');

module.exports = function(passport){
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log('serializing user: ');console.log(user);
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            console.log('deserializing user:',user);
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    login(passport);
    signup(passport);
}
```

login.js:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var User = require('../app/models/user');
    var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

    module.exports = function(passport){

        passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function(req, username, password, done){
            User.findOne({'username': username}, function(err, user){
                if(err){
                    return done(err);
                }
                if(!user){
                    console.log('NENHUM USUARIO ENCONTRADO COM O LOGIN ' + username);
                    return done(null, false);
                }
                if(!validatePassword(user, password)){
                    console.log('PASSWORD INVALIDO');
                    return done(null, false);
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });     
        }
        ));

        var validatePassword = function(user, password){
            return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
        }
    }
```

signup.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var User = require('../app/models/user');
    var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

    module.exports = function(passport){

        passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({

            passReqToCallback: true

        }, function(req, username, password, done){

            findOrCreateUser = function(){
                User.findOne({'username' : username}, function(err, user){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('ocorreu um erro ' + err);
                        return done(err)
                    }
                    if(user){
                        console.log('usuario ja cadastrado');
                        return done(null, false);
                    }else{
                        var novoUsuario = new User();
                        novoUsuario.username = username;
                        novoUsuario.password = createHash(password);
                        novoUsuario.nome = req.param('nome');
                        novoUsuario.email = req.param('email');

                        novoUsuario.save(function(err){
                            if(err){
                                throw err;
                            }
                            console.log('usuario cadastrado com sucesso');
                            return done(null, novoUsuario);
                        });
                    }

                });
            }
            process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);

        }));

        var createHash = function(password){
            return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
        }
    }
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var router = express.Router();
    var jwt = require('jwt-simple');

    var isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next){ 
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }else{
            res.redirect('/');
        }   

    }

    module.exports = function(passport){


        router.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next){
            passport.authenticate('login', function(err, user){
                if(err){
                    res.json({sucesso: false, mensagem: 'Erro ao logar', erro: err});
                }
                else{
                    var token = jwt.encode(user, 'JwTaUtHaNGULAR');
                    return res.send({sucesso: true, token: 'JWT ' + token, mensagem: 'Autenticação OK'});
                }
            })(req, res, next);
        });

        router.post('/api/cadastro', function(req, res, next){
            passport.authenticate('signup', function(err, user){
                if(err){
                    res.json({sucesso: false, mensagem: 'Erro ao criar usuário', erro: err});
                }
                else{
                    res.json({sucesso: true, mensagem: 'Usuario criado com sucesso'});
                }
            })(req, res, next);
        });

        router.get('/api/dashboard/users', isAuthenticated ,function(req, res){
            console.log('request', req)
            Usuario.find({'_id': {$ne: id_user}}, function(err, usuario){
                res.json({sucesso: true, user: usuario});
            });
        });


        return router;
    }
```

models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var UsuarioSchema = new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String, 
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        nome: {
            type: String,
            require: false
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: false,
            require: false
        }
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
```

Answer (score -1):

Como estão os nomes de seus inputs? Devem ser os mesmos do padrão do passport, ou então pode definir com

```
 passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
        // por padrão, local strategy usa username e password
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true 
    },
```

sendo que neste caso a propriedade name do seu input deve seguir a nomeclatura definida.

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Login</button>
    </form>
```